# RTNETLINK answers: File exists after adding ipv6 address

Tags: networking, ipv6

I've been pounding my head against the wall for a while on this and haven't made any headway.

I have a system with a statically assigned ipv4 and ipv6 address.  After boot running `systemctl status networking` results in this:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
       └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-08-27 14:48:50 MST; 8min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 3301 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3275 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3301 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 27 14:48:25 phoenix systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Aug 27 14:48:28 phoenix ifup[3301]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.ens160
Aug 27 14:48:50 phoenix ifup[3301]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Aug 27 14:48:50 phoenix ifup[3301]: Failed to bring up ens160.
Aug 27 14:48:50 phoenix systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 27 14:48:50 phoenix systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Aug 27 14:48:50 phoenix systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 27 14:48:50 phoenix systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**But the interface is actually up and functioning properly.**

If I run `systemctl restart networking`, it fails.  Running `ifdown ens160` just says the interface is not configured.

If I force the interface down with `ifdown --force ens160` it goes down and will come back up with either `ifup ens160` or `systemctl restart networking`.

If I comment out the ipv6 section it's fine after booting.

Here's my interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.XXX.3/24
    gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.1
    dns-search example.org
    dns-nameservers ::1 127.0.0.1

# This is an IPv6 interface
iface ens160 inet6 static
    address XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::3/64
    gateway XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::1
```

This is  with a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04.1 server installation on a vmware cluster with only bind9 and ssh server installed.  The only configuration changes made are a properly configured bind9 and the static IP changes.

I have more than one installation doing the same thing.

I've done plenty of searching and have come up with nothing matching this situation.  My google-fu is usually strong, but it has failed me this time.

Any help I could get would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have something in the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory?

Comment: Does the interface come up when you comment out the gateway line?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, no there's nothing in the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory.

Comment: @maxf, now that's interesting.  I commented out the IPv6 gateway line and it comes up just fine.  My question is, does it automatically use the link local advertised gateway?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it works when you comment out the gateway line, you suffer from an unfortunate race condition: As soon as the link of the interface is up, Linux starts doing *Neighbor Discovery* and accepting *Router Advertisements*, which can put IPv6 routes into your routing table although the interface is not fully configured yet. When the script later tries to add the default route you get

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

To work around this, you can

- either comment out the gateway line (which is the recommended way provided that routes get announced correctly in your network)
- or disable the acceptance of RAs via

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.device.accept_ra=0
  ```

  (device being an actual device, `default` or `all`).

Comment: Thank you for the info.  It seems to happen most with the machines running bind.  That might be slowing the script down enough to make it happen.  Anyway, I'll let the protocol work the gateway out on it's own.

Comment: For VMs, it can also depend on host utilization during boot - it was quite fun to debug back then...

Comment: I am glad I finally found this post after searching the web for 3 months now. It drove me mad, I couldn't find why the guests had proper internet if I delayed their boot, but not when I had them on autostart (clearly this was the host having max. utilisation on boot).

Comment: @maxf I know it's been a while, but could you explain a bit more why this is happening and maybe a fix? When autostarting all of my VM's at the same time at host boot they all fail the networking setup with the same error (RTNETLINK answers: file exists). When I wait for low host utilisation and then boot them manually one at a time it's working without a problem.

Comment: One more detail, my guests fail on this line: ifup[815]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
ifup[815]: /bin/ip addr add 192.168.1.112/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255   
relax ifup[815]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup[815]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
ifup[815]: Failed to bring up ens3. It's weird because this only happens when booting the guest with high host cpu utilisation. And why is that address already there for some reason?

Comment: @maxf not sure if you're still active but I'm still struggling with this issue and really want to finally get rid of it. Can you clear out as to why VMs have this problem during higher host utilization during boot? Is this a QEMU bug? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Qlii256 As written above, it's a race condition. If you either specify the gateway manually or use ND (but not both) it will work. Host CPU utilization just influences the likelihood of observing the race condition, this is not a bug. The excerpt from your log however talks about IPv4, which would make this an entirely different problem.

Comment: @maxf I suffered from the same problem, but as you stated disabling RA works. However, I suffer from another issue that is when I have my configuration just like TS above (IPv4 config first, then IPv6), the networking service always fails with that error on booting. That addr add for the IPv4 address already exists, but I have no clue as to why that is. I hope you can help me diagnose this issue? It does work however without IPv6 or with IPv6 above IPv4 config.